# Is there any reason why .NET's Reflection API uses arrays instead of indexers to retrieve type metadata?

Tags: .net, reflection

Is there any reason why .NET's Reflection API uses arrays instead of indexers to access a type's members/methods/properties/etc.? I understand the overhead of adding collection <s>objects</s> classes such as `MemberInfoCollection`, `MethodInfoCollection`, etc. However, these collection <s>objects</s> classes could be <s>created</s> instantiated on demand. Was the design rationale something other than just "dissuade programmers from using Reflection unless they *really* need it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These APIs were created in .Net 1.0, which didn't have generics.

They couldn't just return a `ReadOnlyCollection<MemberInfo>`, and they were too lazy to create a separate typed collection class for each type they need to return.

(I don't have a source for this belief)

Comment: @SLaks: Awww... But it feels inconsistent to have `SqlParameterCollection`s, `DataRowCollection`s and `DataColumnCollection`s but not `MethodInfoCollection`s or `PropertyInfoCollection`s.

Comment: @Eduardo: Yes; I know, and I don't like it either.

Comment: ADO.Net was made by a different team with a rather different coding style (look in the source)

Comment: Those are stuff in System.Data developed by the ADO.NET team, and with another target group and usage. They need collections that are editable (add parameters, rows, columns), while reflection is read-only.

Comment: They have an even more annoying tendency to use _DataTables_ instead of collections.  (eg, `DbProviderFactories`)

Comment: @Simon Svensson: I think the key point is elegance. Arrays should always be implementation details, never exposed parameter types or return types.

Comment: I would go even further: Arrays should be implementation details of _library collection types_.