# Is it efficient to memoize type metadata when using .NET's Reflection API?

Tags: c#, optimization, reflection

I know premature optimization is the mother of all evil. However, I would like to know which of the following alternatives is more efficient:

- Calling `typeof(T).GetProperties()` many times for the same type `T`.
- Memoizing the retrieved properties into a `Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>`.

Here is some code I wrote using the first approach:

```
private static T MakeElement<T>(SqlDataReader reader) where T : class, new() {
    T element = new T();
    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(); // critical line

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        property.SetValue(element, reader[property.Name], null);

    return element;
}

public static T RetrieveElement<T>() where T : class, new() {
    T element = null;

    actions.Add(delegate(SqlDataReader reader) {
        if (reader.Read())
            element = MakeElement<T>(reader);
    });

    Execute();
    return element;
}

public static List<T> RetrieveList<T>() where T : class, new() {
    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    actions.Add(delegate(SqlDataReader reader) {
        while (reader.Read())
            list.Add(MakeElement<T>(reader));
    });

    Execute();
    return list;
}

// For the sake of completeness, here is the Execute method.
public static void Execute() {
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    connStringBuilder.DataSource     = DataSource;
    connStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = InitialCatalog;
    connStringBuilder.UserID         = UserID;
    connStringBuilder.Password       = Password;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStringBuilder.ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedure, connection)) {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameterCollection parameterCollection = command.Parameters;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in parameters)
            parameterCollection.AddWithValue(parameter.Key, parameter.Value);

        try {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                foreach (Action<SqlDataReader> action in actions) {
                    action(reader);
                    reader.NextResult();
                }
        }
        finally {
            parameters.Clear();
            actions.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

I have already been thinking which each approach could be more efficient:

**For directly calling** `GetProperties`**:**

- The metadata is there anyway. It doesn't have to be reconstructed, just retrieved.

**For memoizing:**

- The metadata might be in a format not directly understandable by the C# application, so there might be some preprocessing involved in `GetProperties`.
- The metadata is there, but the array of `PropertyInfo` isn't, and thus has to be reconstructed.

---

Additional question: [Is there any reason why .NET's Reflection API uses arrays instead of indexers to retrieve type metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417230/is-there-any-reason-why-nets-reflection-api-uses-arrays-instead-of-indexers-to)

Comment: Stack Overflow, thanks for bringing this question to my attention. The author of the question is obviously stupid, and should be downvoted into oblivion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be OK to memoize the result based the Type. You should measure for your situation, but my experience is that calling GetProperties or other reflection methods carry a performance penalty. The result of GetProperties is not going to change at runtime anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Even better:

```
public static class Memoizer<T>
{
    public static readonly PropertyInfo[] Properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
}
```

Just make sure the array isn't changed, or wrap it in a *ReadOnlyCollection* instead.